# Reduce code bloat when trimming an array of strings

Tags: c#, string, collections

I have a string of comma separated values, to get a string array from this I use

```
string[] values = value.Split(',');
```

I want to trim all these values by creating a new list of string and calling a foreach on the array like this

```
 List<string> trimmedValues = new List<string>();

 foreach (string str in values)
     trimmedValues.Add(str.Trim());
```

Is there a more efficent way to do this with less code say by calling a method on the array itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use linq

```
List<string> trimmedValues = values.Select(v => v.trim()).toList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

var myTrimResult = "a ,b   , c ".Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());

The "myTrimResult" variable will contain trimmed elements.

Answer (score 0):

To effectively reduce code bloat, I suggest to use an extension.

Declare a method like the following, in a common context in your project (or even better, in an external helper DLL to carry among different projects):

```
public static List<string> TrimList(this string[] array)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach (var s in array)
    {
        list.Add(s.Trim());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Now, in your code, you can simply use:

```
var trimmedValues = values.TrimList();
```

I find it more readable than using LINQ expression in code